# Not getting dynamic updates of Mysql query in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

Suppose I have below code. I am connecting to "sales" database in mysql through python.

```
#cell 1
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', 
                               user='root', 
                               passwd='1234', 
                               database='sales') #, database='db1'
cur = mydb.cursor()
```

Then fetching total number of rows in table "customer" using function chk_rows().

```
#cell 2
def chk_nrows():
    cur.execute('select count(*) from customer')
    nrows=cur.fetchone()[0]
    return nrows

chk_nrows()
```

Suppose there are 5 rows in customer table and I ran chk_rows() function once. I get the output 5 here. Now if I INSERT 1 row in customer table by going in mysql IDE(or workbench) the total number of rows are now = 6.

But when I run chk_nrows() function(or cell 2) again it gives me 5.

I want to know why it is still giving 5 and not 6?

Note: If I insert the code of cell 1 inside the function of cell 2, then I get correct updated results. But connecting to database again and again doesn't seems to be a right thing to me. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to reconnect to DB to get updates. It sounds like something is caching the query result, but I don't think mysql.connector does that.

Comment: What if you create a new cursor without reconnecting?

Comment: have you commited the insert?

Comment: @Barmar even after creating a new cursor at the start of function and closing it at the end of function, its not working.

Comment: @nbk Yes I commited it.